# Using source annotation on a field in an annonymous inner class?

Tags: java, annotations, preprocessor, auto-generate

I'm new to preprocessors and am trying to do the following code:

```
public class foo {

 private Map<String, Runnable> reflectivelyInitializedMap;

 private MyObject bar = new MyObject() {
   @ExternalApi
   private Runnable makePublic;
 }

 // I want to generate the following method:
 public void makePublic(){
   reflectivelyInitializedMap.get("makePublic").run();
 }

}
```

I am not able to catche the inner annotated field "makePublic" in the preprocessor.
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems impossible. I did the following:

```
public class foo {

 private Map<String, Runnable> reflectivelyInitializedMap;

 @ExternalApi("makePublic")
 private MyObject bar = new MyObject() {
   private Runnable makePublic;
 }

 // I want to generate the following method:
 public void makePublic(){
   reflectivelyInitializedMap.get("makePublic").run();
 }

}
```